# Detect if a function is bounded to the scope with &

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive `popup` that has an isolated scope with only a function binding in it:

**Template**

```
<popup>
    <div class="confirm-button" ng-show="showConfirmButton" ng-click="onConfirm()">confirm</div>
</popup>
```

**Directive and controller**

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('popup', [function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            onConfirm: "&"
        },
        controller: 'popup-ctrl',
        templateUrl: "partials/directives/popup.html"
    };
}]);

angular.module('app.controllers').controller('popup-ctrl', [function ($scope) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.showConfirmButton = typeof $scope.onConfirm === 'function'; // ALWAYS TRUE :(
    //...
}]);
```

**Usage**

```
<popup onConfirm="doSomething()"></popup>
```

What I want to do is simple : if no function has been bounded to &onConfirm, I want to hide the confirm button.

This doesn't work, since `typeof $scope.onConfirm === 'function';` is always true. If I inspect my scope at runtime, I see that `$scope.onConfirm.toString()` evaluates to - whether I bind the function or not :

```
"function (locals) {
    return parentGet(scope, locals);
}"
```

Anybody knows a way to detect if some function has been bound to &onConfirm or not?

**Edit**

Here's a Plunkr of it (simplified) :

http://plnkr.co/edit/WFHfEL2OyP4OZVdVNh7s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a linking function to the directive and check for the attribute value to see if there is anything assigned:-

```
   link:function(scope,elm, attr){
       scope.showConfirmButton = !!attr.onConfirm;
    },
```

Also note that since your isolated scope has defined the attribute as `onConfirm` you need to use it as `on-confirm`. i.e

```
<popup on-confirm="doSomething()"></popup>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsAkT01jxyvp9RFSi3RE?p=preview)**

It is not possible to look for the the function reference that is bound to the isolated scope binding with '&' as far as i know, since they are evaluated internally going up the scope chain.

Or as a hack you could look into parent scope:

```
.directive('popup', ['$parse',function ($parse) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "E",

        scope: {
            onConfirm: "&"
        },
        controller: 'popup-ctrl',
        link:function(scope,elm, attr){

           var elm = $parse(attr.onConfirm)(scope.$parent);
           scope.showConfirmButton = !!attr.onConfirm && hasFunction(attr.onConfirm);

           function hasFunction(func) {
             return angular.isFunction($parse(func.substring(0, func.indexOf('(')))(scope.$parent));
           }

        },
        template: '<div class="confirm-button" ng-show="showConfirmButton" ng-click="onConfirm()">confirm</div>'
    };
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AS275Up8eP5XPxTMDLsG?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks, the linking function do the trick! Thanks for noting the error in my Plunkr. I'm not sure about looking into the parent, I will have to look deeper into it, maybe I'll learn something.